# Visual Studio 2013 - Add New Scripts in /Scripts/ Folder in .csproj

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've begun to really enjoy a quick contextual menu that appears when adding new Typescript files into my Visual Studio Web Project. You can see from this image that I can quickly select that I want to create a typescript file without much fuss. Right clicking all I have to do is go through a folder in Scripts > Add > Typescript File to make said file.

[image: Scripts > Add > Typescript File]

I've begun adding my scripts to another referenced .csproj class library, and unfortunately for me, the context menu doesn't work in the same way. Shown here:
[image]

I'm wondering if there is a way to reclaim this menu context without having to convert this project into anything different? Or, if changing the project will have minimal impact on everything else.